# Effect on current due to relative motion of load in homopolar generator

Tags: motor, generator, inductance, faradays-law

[image]

Description of figure -

A homopolar generator in which disc is rotating with constant angular frequency with respect to ground frame and a uniform steady magnetic field is present perpendicular to disc plane .

I wanted to understand what will be effect on current through load due to relative motion of load in two cases (below) for homopolar generator and in general any generator.

Question-

Is current through loadZ (figure)  same in following cases?

1.a brush is attached(fig) to circumstances of disc whose velocity (of brush not disc)with respect to ground frame is zero and then load is connected to a that brush and axel(center).

2.if load is  directly connected between axel(center) and circumference of disc without brush i.e load is also rotating with same velocity as disc.

I thought current should be same in both cases but I'm not sure because we mostly read in books only 1st case is mentioned almost in every book but not 2nd case.

hope  someone can help me !

Comment: There is no voltage if the brushes contact always the same sector of the disc.

Comment: Hi @Janka ,but what is reason for no voltage ?

Answer (score 1):

If the disk velocity in case 1 is zero, the current will be zero.

The total resistance in the loop that includes the load is the resistance of the load plus the resistances of the conductors connecting the load, the resistance of the connections of the conductors at the center and circumference and the resistance of the disk. Sliding connections at  the center and circumference will presumably be higher than fixed connection methods. The effect on current will be determined by the difference in the connection resistance compared to the total resistance in the loop.

For current to flow in the second case, the magnetic field must be prevented from passing through the moving conductors that connect the load between the circumference and the center of the disk.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I think you misunderstood 1st case disc is always rotating with constant angular velocity relative to ground frame of reference ,it is brush which has zero velocity with respect to ground

Comment: I suspected that the velocity of the disk was not zero, but the statement of the first case actually states that the velocity of the disk is zero.

Comment: Ok ,I edited it to avoid any confusion!

Comment: but in 2nd case if load form a closed loop with both ends of disc , isn't it impossible to prevent magnetic field to pass through moving conductor ?

Comment: Yes, it would very likely be impossible.